# MYSQL REGEXP_REPLACE after numbers

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I want to replace data after numbers with '' using regex_replace.

For example:

input        --> output
`MA0244891-D`  --> `MA0244891`
`MA0244891`    --> `MA0244891`
`MA0244891D`   --> `MA0244891`
`0244891D`   --> `0244891`

I tried a few regex_replace as below:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(rk.mystring, '[^0-9]+', ''))` --> only get numbers
`REGEXP_REPLACE(rk.mystring, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ''))` ---> get alphanumeric including the last characters
`REGEXP_REPLACE(rk.mystring, '[^a-zA-Z][^0-9]+', ''))` ---> almost correct but truncate numbers at the back

Appreciate your kind help

Comment: To remove anything after last digit: [`REGEXP_REPLACE(mystring, '(.*\\d).*', '$1')`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qgZxEMYM1RZyLN74udfh9x/0)

Comment: AAA111BBB222CCC --> ?

Comment: @bobblebubble i have tried and it works! tqvm

Comment: You have recently obtained voting privileges, kindly [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answers (see [how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/)) that you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove any non-alphanumeric in the string and any letters at the end of string:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(rk.mystring, '[^0-9A-Za-z]|[a-zA-Z]+$', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mWRQR/1).

*Details*:

- `[^0-9A-Za-z]` - any char other than ASCII digits and letters
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z]+$` - one or more ASCII letters at the end of string.

Comment: i have tried the answer and it works! tqvm

Answer (score 1):

You may replace on the pattern `-?[A-Z]$`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mystring, '-?[A-D]$', '') AS mystring_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a running [SQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bbdec2e113a1652954e4a0b7c6ba126).